# On just 1 (new) page of my site there appears a wordpress footer with copyright 2012 which I want to remove

Tags: footer

On my infinite pro site, I made a new page, which shows not only my footer with copyright, but also a wordpress copyright 2012!
I cannot find how to remove the last one.

All the other pages are ok!

https://www.physioalternative.com/rejuvance-facial-massage-online-course/

Answer (score 0):

C. Vloemans,

It looks like the theme has two different footers and the call for the footer is in the page template. All of the other pages have the same footer so you just have to change the Page template. Open the page in question with the page editor match the Page template with one of the other pages, this option is going to be on the right under Page Attributes from the page editor. Hope this helps.